# How to pass array value in table which is inside ngFor?

Tags: angular

I want to pass the array value in the table which is inside the ngFor directive.In below code you can see table row is add when select the option and the row are display,now in this row td I want to display the array value.

```js
export class GlComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  select:number[]=[];
  carat:number[]=[];
  Arr = Array;
  ornament_name: Array<string> = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.select=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
    this.carat=[24,22,21,20,19,18];
    this.ornament_name["val1","val2","val3","val4","val5","val6"];
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit(){}
  
  table_Toggle=true;
  selectMethod(value){
    this.tableToggle=false; 
  }
  }
```

```html
<select name="select_no" [(ngModel)]="selectedvalue" (change)="selectMethod(index)">
  <option [ngValue]="p" *ngFor="let p of select;">{{p}}</option>
</select>

<form>
 <table class="table" [hidden]="tableToggle">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>S.No</th>
           <th>Carat</th>
           <th>Weight (Gms)</th>
           <th>Loan Amount</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let i of Arr(selectedvalue).fill(); let index=index;">
            <td>{{index+1}}</td>
            <td>
               <select name="select_carat" [(ngModel)]="carat_Value+carat_index">
                 <option [ngValue]="carat" *ngFor="let carat of carat;let carat_index = index;"> 
                 {{carat}}
                 </option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td>
               <input type="number" class="form-control required" name="goldInGram" [(ngModel)]="[index].value" autocomplete="off" min="1" max="500">
            </td>
            <td *ngFor="let display_Value of ornament_name;let array_IN=index;">
               {{display_Value}}
            </td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
  </form>
```

> I want to display the **ornament_name** array at the **display_Value**
>   position, how can i do this?

Comment: Do you just want to display the array or is there any calculation

Comment: Array will contain the calculated value and then this will display on table.

Comment: You will display all of them in each row?

Comment: array will contain calculated value then each row only display one value.This value will get change via row increase.

Comment: Okay, check my answer and let me know if you want like this

Comment: yes Adrita,thank you for your answer.

Comment: hello Adrita, When i am console the  value from table containing  select and input it show undefine. I can't get why this show undefine,can you tell me why show this...

Comment: I will look into this after 10 minutes

Comment: Can you specify which part

Comment: selecter and input which is inside the table.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<td>
    {{ornament_name[index]}}
</td>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eeqis7)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now is adding a new table cell for each value in this array.
This means your table does not correspond with your table header.

I would suggest to do something like this:

```
<td>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let display_Value of ornament_name;let array_IN=index;">
    {{display_Value}}
  </ng-container>
</td>
```

Or if you want the value on each row use a `div` instead a `ng-container`

**ng-container**
This is a Angular specific component that does not render anything in html.

Comment: hello can you help me to trace problem, When i am console the value from table containing select and input it show undefine. I can't get why this show undefine,can you tell me why show this..

Comment: can you make a stackblitz? its easier to debug